# Paste Print output in a text file

Tags: output-formatting, output

I have a For[...] cycle which calls a function. When the function is at work, it prints some text-string through the command Print[...].

Since I iterate the action of the function for 1000 times, the output printed starts to become very long and Mathematica starts to get slow.

Is there any way to modify the Print command or to send the output buffer into a text file which is instantaneously updated?

Comment: Inside the `For` loop you could print only each `n`-th value. If `i` is your loop variable then try: `If[Mod[i, n] == 0, Print[...];`

Comment: I cannot do that. I am interested in every single output. But it is too long and I want to send it to a text file

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Block` to modify the behaviour of `Print`.

```
f[x_] := Print[x]

printlist = {};

Block[{Print = AppendTo[printlist, {##}] &},
 Table[f[x], {x, 1, 10}];
 ]

First /@ printlist
```

> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}

Alternatively you can redirect the output stream.

```
f[x_] := Print[x]

tmp = $Output;
streamlist = $Output = {OpenWrite[]};

Table[f[x], {x, 1, 10}];

Close@Last@streamlist;
$Output = tmp;
printoutput = ReadList@First@Last@streamlist
```

> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like:

```
SetAttributes[printToFile, HoldFirst]
printToFile[expr_, file_] := Block[{$Output=OpenAppend[file]},
    Internal`WithLocalSettings[
        Null,
        expr,
        Close[$Output]
    ]
]
```

Example usage:

```
printToFile[
    Print[f[x]];Print["asdf"];Print[x/3],
    file
]
```